# Can't install PowerShell 4.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to install PowerShell 4.0 on a Windows 2008R2 server

Installed `Windows6.1-KB2819745-x64-MultiPkg.msu` with no errors or warning

But when I run up PowerShell and check the $host.version, it's still `3 0 -1 -1`

Compared it to a scratch virtual machine I have with Win2008R2 on, and there version shows as `4 0 -1 -1`

And to be double sure, I checked the file version of the `powershell.exe`

- Problem server is 6.2.9200.1398
- Virtual is 6.3.9600.16406

Comment: It looks like service pack 1 and .Net 4.5 are prerequisites and need to be installed first. A re-boot may be required. (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21016.how-to-install-windows-powershell-4-0.aspx )

Comment: @Charmon Thanks for that ... yeap, the servers are only NET 4.0, whereas my virtual is NET 4.5   Please add as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like service pack 1 and .Net 4.5 are prerequisites and need to be installed first. A re-boot may be required. (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21016.how-to-install-windows-powershell-4-0.aspx)